# Get values from a custom table in wordpress using post meta

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Im a little new to this kind of PHP / Query so please cut me some slack lol.

I have the following.

Post type called $event and a plugin that manages $events. Long story short the locations for events are stored in a custom table. Each event has a post meta "_location_id" which corresponds to the row ID in wp_em_locations table.

I can get the _location_id using:

```
get_post_meta($eventID, '_location_id', true);
```

However I have no idea how to proceed when it comes to getting values from the different columns that correspond to the row ID in the custom table.

My purpose is displaying a list of events with the location name next to it.

Im now trying the code from below with an edit for the unique id column name and the column name Im looking to get data from and Im returning nothing.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$location_id=get_post_meta($eventID, '_location_id', true);
echo $location_id;
//the above returns the correct row ID                                          
$locations=$wpdb->get_results('select {location_name} from `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'em_locations` where `location_id`=\'' . $location_id . '\'', ARRAY_A);
    if (!is_null($locations) && count($locations) > 0){
    foreach ($locations as $location){
    echo $location['location_name'];
    }
    } else {
    //no locations
    } ?>
```

@Flyer's example didt work for me so I thought perhaps I was doing something wrong so checked up on the codex and went with the following.

```
global $wpdb;
   $location_id=get_post_meta($eventID, '_location_id', true);
   $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT location_id, location_name FROM wp_em_locations WHERE location_id = '. $location_id );
   var_dump($myrows);
   /* gives the following
   array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#215 (2) { ["location_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["location_name"]=> string(9) "Liverpool" } }*/
   echo $myrows["location_name"];
   //shows nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
global $wpdb;
$location_id=get_post_meta($eventID, '_location_id', true);
$locations=$wpdb->get_results('select `location_id`,`location_name`,`location_town`, `location_city` from `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'em_locations` where `location_id`=\'' . $location_id . '\'', ARRAY_A);
if (!is_null($locations) && count($locations) > 0)
{
    foreach ($locations as $location)
    {
//do whatever you need with results, accessing them like $location['ID'] for example
    }
}
else
{
//no locations
}
```

Comment: Best answer so far, will try it out.

Comment: Ive added your example with my edits above, however its not working, what do you think?

Comment: @AlexKnopp you don't need `{}`, that was to show that `list of columns you need` was just a place holder. I have edited it to get ID and location name (assuming `location_name` is the actual name of that column in DB)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The primary (first) column in the table is 'location_id' and the columns I need are 'location_name, location_town and location_city'. Also, Im already inside the loop, do I need the foreach?

Comment: @AlexKnopp updated to reflect needed columns. And yes, this foreach goes through locations (rows) returned by mysql query

Comment: then I assume to echo out the value in the location_name column I would use echo $location['location_name'];

Comment: Ive edited the original post as your example wasnt working for me, I checked it out with the WP Codex and tried the 2nd batch of code and whilst my dump is returning what i need, the echo doesnt produce anything. Syntax issue?

Comment: My latest edit should work fine for you, the one you have in a question is an old one.